# Load video dynamically into Flowplayer from VB codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, flowplayer

I have on page load (VB) request.querystring and want to load Flowplayer using the querystring results. I dont know how to get the value from the querystring in codebehind to the flowplayer. Any suggestions?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim videoName As String = Request.QueryString("FileName")
    Dim thumb As String = Request.QueryString("Thumb")
End Sub

<div data-swf="http://mywebsite.com/player/flowplayer.swf" class="flowplayer play-button"
  data-ratio="0.416" data-embed="false">
  <video poster="NEED QUERYSTRING 'THUMB' VALUE HERE">         
     <source type="video/mp4" src="NEED 'VIDEONAME' VALUE HERE"/>         
  </video>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to get the querystring values in the form by using `Page.Request.QueryString`

**Example**

```
<div data-swf="http://mywebsite.com/player/flowplayer.swf" class="flowplayer play-button"
  data-ratio="0.416" data-embed="false">
  <video poster="<% Page.Request.QueryString['Thumb'] %>">         
     <source type="video/mp4" src="<% Page.Request.QueryString['FileName'] %>"/>         
  </video>      
</div>
```